# default mount point changed for external HD

Tags: mount, 13.10, external-hdd, automount, mountpoint

The default mount point for my external HD changed when upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10. Now the username is added as an extra level before the hd label.

So it used to be

```
/media/nameofhd
```

and now it became

```
/media/username/nameofhd
```

This breaks a lot of links I have set up to this disk.

I know that I can mount it manually and even automatically through /etc/fstab. What I want to know is why this behaviour changed and how I can change it back to the original?

blkid and fdisk don't show anything suspicious.

thx!

Comment: Well not entirely. I also asked for the rationale behind this changed behavior and this is not handled in the supposed duplicate. The questions are indeed very related though, and both should be merged if possible. Especially the answer of @Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am not completely sure. But I have not found other explanation)

If we take a look to the /media directory, the /media/username directory belongs to root:

```
drwxr-x---+  3 root root 4096 nov 11 09:46 mmartin/
```

but the drive mounted inside belongs to the user:

```
drwx------  5 mmartin mmartin 32768 jan  1  1970 JAN_EXT/
```

If we mount an EXT4 filesystem (for example) we can create new directories or files on the hard drive root. In the past, we had to create directories with root privileges inside the first level of an EXT4 filesystem, and later grant permissions to the user.

Comment: This may indeed be the rationale behind the change. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found official doc :-(